# How to add Contact info in Android App with Xamarin

Tags: c#, contacts, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing a **simple** application which will store a contact name and ip address.

In my mind i imagined i would have a text field where i could enter a name, and another text field for the ip address and then a button which when clicked stored the contents of the text fields into some kind of array that could then be called up to show the contacts added.

I'm working in **Xamarin** for Android and writing my code in **C#** - except i'm not totally sure where to begin with this task.

Anyone know where to start with this on C#? Examples or existing works would be incredibly useful as i'm very much a beginner when it comes to programming!

Comment: @Kerry i am using C# because i haven't learned Java yet. I want to build this application using C# as i have a very basic understanding in this language and do not want to get discouraged by learning something i find too difficult. After i get this working i will likely move on to other languages - and for this particular application, i am not fussed about it being cross-platform.

Comment: Mono is officially supported by Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin has a [github repository](https://github.com/xamarin) with a lot of different samples and ready made apps.

Also the [Xamarin documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/) for Xamarin.Android is very useful, as it contains API docs, tutorials and descriptions for some of the samples in the repository along with additional samples.

There are also a couple of books, which gives you a good basis of knowledge of how to use Mono for Android/Xamarin.Android:

- [Professional Android Programming with Mono for Android and .NET/C#](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-1118026438.html)
- [Mobile Development with C#](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024002.do)