# Xamarin.Mobile Create, Update & Delete Contacts

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.mobile

On what platforms does Xamarin.Mobile allow creation, updating and deleting of Contacts? Specifically, does it allow this on Android? Doesn't seem to be the case, according to my research of the APIs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say 'No' based on both the API and the Getting Started page for Xamarin... for Android `Xamarin.Contacts` requires the `READ_CONTACTS` permission which is (surprise) strictly for reading the contacts.

Source: [**Xamarin.Mobile Getting Started**](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile)

For potential solutions outside of using the `Xamarin.Mobile` component, check out [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15467031/2395124) on a similar thread.